# Solution to Dirac equation with external source

Tags: gauge-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, yang-mills

The Dirac equation is:

\begin{equation}
\left[i\gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}-iA_{\mu})-m\right]\psi=0,             \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $A_\mu$ is a gauge field. The solution to this equation is:
\begin{equation}
\psi=\exp\Big(i\int^xA_{\mu}dx^{\mu}\Big)\psi_0,                \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\psi_0$ is the solution to the Dirac equation in the absence of the gauge field.
Now suppose there is an external field $B_\mu$, which has an $SU(3)$ symmetry such that $B_{\mu} = B_{\mu}^{a}T_{3}^{a}$ where $T_{3}^{a} = \frac{1}{2}\lambda^{a}$ with $\lambda^{a}$being Gell-Mann matrices. Then the Dirac equation becomes
\begin{equation}
\left[i\gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}-iA_{\mu})-m\right]\psi = B_{\mu}^{a}T_{3}^{a}\psi,  \tag{3}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\left[i\gamma^{\mu}\left(\partial_{\mu}-iA_{\mu}+ iB_{\mu}^{a}T_{3}^{a}\right)-m\right]\psi = 0.           \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Then, in analogy to eq. (2), can we write solution to eq. (4) as
\begin{equation}
\psi=\exp\left[i\int^x \left(A_{\mu}-B_{\mu}^{a}T_{3}^{a}\right)dx^{\mu}\right]\psi_0?              \tag{5}
\end{equation}
If not, how should we solve eq. (4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your claimed solutions are valid in general. In order for an expressions like
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) =\exp\Big(i\int^xA_{\mu}dx^{\mu}\Big)\psi_0,                
\end{equation}
to be a valid function of positionm the integral has to be independent of the path chosen. This is only the case if the $F_{\mu\nu}= \partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$ gauge  field is zero.

In general, given an equation such as your Eq (1), you have to work hard to solve it. The case of a uniform magnetic field is the simplest example. In that case there  is a solution in terms of associated Legendre polynomials that is related to the solution of the 2 dimensional Harmonic oscillator in polar coordinates. I suggest you work though that example  and find it.